# Getting the list of deployed versions in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

Short of writing a microservice which runs the appcfg command in the shell ("appcfg -q -A my-app-engine list_versions") and returns the list of the deployed versions, is there a way from within a deployed application to query for the list of deployed versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of Java it seems that `com.google.appengine.api.modules.ModuleService` ([javadoc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/modules/ModulesService.html)) is what you are looking for. It provides the below method returning the set of versions that are available to the given module.

```
Set<String> ModuleService.getVersions(String module)
```

In case of Python look at `google.appengine.api.modules.modules` module ([pythondoc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.modules.modules.html)) that has similar function.

```
get_versions(module=None)
```